# Can I call methods on Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a new token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can I call methods on Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a new token? 
I want to make the ability to update the token myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId#deleteInstanceId()) to delete the current token.

Be sure to read the Firebase documentation on [monitoring the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register), as there are more cases where the token might get refreshed.